# Customize Android Launcher from source

Tags: android

I want to customize the Launcher of android (from source of google), my question is:
Where should I start? (Download the Launcher source)
If I want to place some shortcut on home screen, where is the class to do?
How to run that Launcher on Android Emulator?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I'd advise against this. The default android launcher uses several APIs that aren't available to the public, and it took me around 9 hours to just get it to compile. Even then, parts of it wouldn't work. For example, I could see through the current Page into the next one. Also, widgets don't work because the launcher uses some private method to add them, which is only available to apps signed by the same key as the ROM.

You should probably work with the home screen replacement SDK sample provided. However, if you still want to do this, download Launcher2 from the github repository and start working through errors one by one.

Comment: You can get it to compile with quite a bit of work. Some method calls will be to setFastSomething(). Just remove the fast and those will be fine. Then you'll have some classes like TableMaskFilter. These will need to be removed completely. Even after you've removed all the errors, it still won't work fully. I'll stand by my previous advice and ask you to work with the SDK sample.

Comment: Okay, I will try with SDK sample :-)

Comment: Is this still the case with Launcher3?