# Compile Android Open Source Launcher in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-launcher, cyanogenmod

I want to build my own customized launcher based on launcher3 though I found it very difficult to compile.

Also read this old post: [Customize Android Launcher from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276656/customize-android-launcher-from-source)

Is it still the case that it is difficult to compile?

What would you recommend as a base for a new launcher?
- launcher3
- cyanogenmod trebuchet launcher (EverythingMe based their launcher on it)
- Others?